# Instead of string method returns Kotlin.Unit

Tags: android, kotlin, jsonobjectrequest

I have a  method which should return String value. The return value is correct and shows needed value string but in fragment I received Kotlin.Unit instead of that value.
Here what I see when debug:
[image]

here is my function:

```
  fun getName() {
    var name: String? = null
    uploadPerson({ res ->
        name = res.getJSONObject("person").getString("name")

    },
        { err ->
            Log.d("TAG", "error: $err")

        })
    val id = "5586"
  
   val url =
        "https://$id/api/person/get?&$name"
    val resRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, null,
        { response ->

        },
        { error ->
           
        }
    )
    queue.add(resRequest)
 }
```

`uploadPerson` function:

```
fun uploadPerson(
       
        result: (res: JSONObject) -> Unit,
        error: ((err: String) -> Unit)? = null
    ) {


        val params = HashMap<String, Any>()
        params["id"] = person.id
        params["name"] = person.name
       
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>)

        val id = "5545"
    
        val requestUrl = "https://id/api/person/UploadPerson";

        val jsonObjectRequest =
            object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestUrl, jsonObject,
                { response ->

                    try {
                        if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                            val resultObj = response.getJSONObject("person")

                        } else {

                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    uploadResult(response);
                },
                { error ->
                    // TODO: Handle error

                    uploadError?.invoke(error.toString());
                }
            ) {
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    return getAuthHeaders()
                }
            }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

I think that it is because of result `uoloadPerson` function is `Unit` and I need return String type in `getName` function. But I can't understand how to fix this problem

Comment: change `result: (res: JSONObject) -> Unit` to `result: (res: JSONObject) -> String` ?

Comment: in this case i get error here:  `uploadPerson({ res ->
        name = res.getJSONObject("person").getString("name")

    },` : `Type mismatch. Required: String? Found: Unit`

Comment: Assignments aren't expressions in kotlin, use `res.getJSONObject("person").getString("name").also { name = it }`, which returns the left side after evaluating block.

Comment: @ Animesh Sahu thanks. but in this case nothing changed. I still get result `kotlin.unit`

Comment: Are you returning `name` from `#getName()` to the Fragment ? i don't see a return statement . Not sure how are you returning because `uploadPerson` is a non blocking Async call .

Comment: just add  return name at the end of fun getName() before closing } also define getName() : String? {.....

Comment: @ Ankit Aman but I need to get value from response, from here: `val resRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, null,
        { response ->

        },
        { error ->
           
        }`

Comment: @ADM , I call `getName` method like this:  `fun getNameClient(): String {
        return MyClass.getName().toString()
    }`